# Null parameters in C# WebService

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, soap

I was handed the WSDL of a WebService I must implement and generated its basic structure from it (tried with both svcutils.exe from the .NET SDK and the WSDL.blue plugin for Visual Studio). Someone will consume this WebService, and I cannot change the type of requests they do. Here's a sample SOAP request I have captured from my client:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<env:Header></env:Header>
<env:Body>
<ns1:setNetworkActivatorResponse xmlns:ns1='http://client.response.ws.meh/'>
    <OrderResponse>
        <orderHeader>
            <clientID>trD-125205</clientID>
            <description>0</description>
            <operation>trD</operation>
            <orderKey>
                <applicationContext>
                    <URL>http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8181/</URL>
                    <hostName>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</hostName>
                </applicationContext>
<applicationDN>XYPT</applicationDN>
                    <primaryKey>170809</primaryKey>
                </orderKey>
                <priority>1</priority>
            </orderHeader>
            <info>
                Yadda Yadda Yadda text.
            </info>
        </OrderResponse>
    </ns1:setNetworkActivatorResponse>
    </env:Body>
    </env:Envelope>
```

This request calls the right method on the WebServer (setNetworkActivatorResponse()), however the method's parameter OrderResponse is passed as null. I believe it has something to do with namespaces, because if I modify the request and add the ns1 namespace to OrderResponse (like `<ns1:OrderResponse> </ns1:OrderResponse>`) the parameter is passed correctly and the OrderResponse object is available in the C# method.

My method is defined as a typical C# .NET WebService:

```
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[WebService(Namespace = "http://client.response.ws.meh/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://client.response.ws.meh/")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace = "http://client.response.ws.meh/", ConfigurationName = "ResponseClientWebService")]
public class ResponseClientWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public void setNetworkActivatorResponse(OrderResponse OrderResponse)
    {
        String meh = OrderResponse.info;
    }

}
```

And here is my OrderResponse class:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.233")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://client.response.ws.na.agorang.ptinovacao.pt/")]
public partial class OrderResponse
{
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public string messageID;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public OrderHeader orderHeader;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public string info;
}
```

The required classes (OrderResponse and such) are defined and implemented as well. Any idea what I can change in my code (seeing as I can't change the client's request to have the ns1 namespace on OrderResponse) to make it able to accept the SOAP request?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the `OrderResponse` class?

Comment: Sure, I've added it to the original post.

Comment: Have you solve this problem? I've to implement a WS and the client, out of my control, sends something like yours. The problem seems to be with the namespace prefix because if I remove it the parameter is passed otherwise it is null (not parsed I supposed).

Comment: In all honesty, I have no idea, it was 11 years and hundreds of projects ago :V

Answer (score 0):

The `XmlTypeAttribute` line on the OrderResponse class is the reason your webservice is requiring the  to exist in a specific namespace. To fix this, I'm pretty sure that you can just remove this line of code from your file.

However, removing this line from generated code wouldn't be an optimal solution because regeneration from the WSDL will put this line back into the code. Ideally, you would modify the WSDL so that the  element is defined to exist in a blank target namespace.

Comment: Nope, even if I remove the XmlTypeAttribute the parameter is not recognized without the namespace.